# SlideMenu Above App Bar Android Studio

Tags: android

I have created a slideMenu & when i press the button to show my menu it shows above the App Bar instead of below it. I changed some of my xml props to see if i can fix it but so far no result

[app_bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b99O.png) 
[app_bar_part_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmMGq.png)

Comment: Rest of links because i have low reputation
DRAWER:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/HKYWK.png
Activity Main  http://i.stack.imgur.com/D06nj.png

Answer (score 0):

I think i know whats the problem you are facing, still i cant be sure without seeing your code.
so please try as follow,
changes need to be done in your activity xml inside NavigationView tag

```
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

And check if you are having your theme set to AppTheme.NoActionBar change it to AppTheme
Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: I posed my code & i tried chaging in my activity_main (where i call the drawer) to false but it still doesn't work

Comment: you need to change in NavigationView inside drawer layout and also change the theme in mainfest from AppTheme.NoActionBar to AppTheme

Comment: when i change NoActionBar to Apptheme app crashes 
  Manifest http://i.stack.imgur.com/TZXyZ.png